# 8 meassurements (cube) in 3D space - interpolate between the values by one 3D position

Tags: 3d, position, interpolation

I measured data in a 3d space. lets say temperature in a room for example. the 8 measurement points are arranged like the edges of a cube. I have room coordinates and temperature data for each point.

Now I track a moving person within the same space. Based on the person's actual position I want to interpolate between the 8 values to assume the temperature at that point in space.

Answer (score 0):

I think weighted average based on measurement points' distances to the person will give the value you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Try the trilinear interpolation. See this Wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation) for details